# Determine what a link's pathname would be if followed?

Tags: javascript, url

I have a link like this:

```html
<a href="./somepage.html">This link goes to some page.</a>
```

I have a variable containing the `pathname` of the page *after* visiting that page. It looks like so:

```
/C:/work/so/test/somepage.html
```

I'm currently comparing them by doing this:

```
curLocation = window.location.pathname;
pathname = curLocation.substring(0, curLocation.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + elements[i].getAttribute('href');
var oldPathname = '/C:/work/so/test/somepage.html'; //pretend this variable is already set, and not hardcoded
if(pathname == oldPathname) {
    //do stuff
}
```

However that won't work, because `pathname` will equal this:

```
/C:/work/so/test/./somepage.html
```

...but `oldPathname` (the actual resulting path after navigating that link) will look like this:

```
/C:/work/so/test/somepage.html
```

How can I reliably check if those two links are the same? Is there a way to "simulate" clicking through a link, and find what the resulting `window.location.pathname` would be?

Comment: pathname = pathname.replace('./', '');

Comment: @Angels Well that was just an example, I don't know what other cases there might be where a URL is the same but not when appended to the current directory.

Comment: instead of `elements[i].getAttribute('href')` use `elements[i].href` ? this will have the full path

Comment: @Angels If, for example, the `<a>` looked like the following, it would still reach the file but your solution would no longer work: `<a href="../test/secondpage.html">This link goes to the second page.</a>`

Comment: Nah, it will be the same if all your other files will be in the same directory. This change is only because your href starts with './'.You won't be able to change it. That path is relative to current html document.

Comment: @Angels The HTML part isn't mine, hence I can't guarantee what silly things other people may have done (like going above the current directory and straight back in, as in my comment example).

Comment: @JaromandaX Aha! That works perfectly, thank you! I didn't know `href` was a property like that. Write that as an answer and I'll accept it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use .href rather than getAttribute('href')

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a => console.log(a.href))
```

```html
<a href="./link1.html">Link 1</a>
<a href="../link2.html">Link 2</a>
<a href="../folder/link3.html">Link 3</a>
```